# Как снять атрибут только чтение

Tags: c#, .net, файловая-система

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема - не могу снять с папки атрибут только чтение. Делаю это так:

```
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyFolder").Attributes;
    Console.WriteLine(dirInfo.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
    dirInfo = FileAttributes.Normal;
    Console.WriteLine(dirInfo.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
```

После выполнения кода на консоль выводится сначала True (папка имеет атрибут), затем False (атрибут снят, что вроде логично), но когда я запускаю код снова, то опять те же результаты - True (он снова появился) и False (снова исчез). Можно ли как-то снять этот атрибут программно? (вручную кстати тоже не очень получается(()

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что у Вас проблемы со ссылками.

Перепишите код следующим образом:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\MyFolder");
Console.WriteLine(dirInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
dirInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
Console.WriteLine(dirInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly));
```